# How to render a whole UITableView as an UIImage in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have simple `UITableView` with some data. The table's height is greater than the screen size. Now I need to catch screenshot of this table (a whole table). I know that cells after the content are dequeued, but maybe there is a way how to capture this. isn't it?

Comment: Could you please check and help me on attached question. I trying to change the Tableview to ImageView. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70879552/uitableview-to-uiimage-swift.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
 func generateImage(tblview:UITableView) ->UIImage{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tblview.contentSize);
        tblview.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
        tblview.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        let row = tblview.numberOfRowsInSection(0)
        let numberofRowsThatShowOnScreen = 4
        var scrollCount = row / numberofRowthatShowinscreen
        
        for var i = 0; i < scrollCount; i++ {
            tblview.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: (i+1) * numberofRowsThatShowOnScreen, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
            tblview.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        }
        
        let image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image;
}
```

and after call method like this.

```
 var imageView = UIImageView()
     imageView.image = generateImage(tableView)
```

Comment: This still only captures the cells on screen for me.

Comment: Hello @Parth, Could you please check and help me on attached question. I trying to change the Tableview to ImageView. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70879552/uitableview-to-uiimage-swift.

Answer (score 3):

My solution for Swift 4 !

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UITableView {

    func asFullImage() -> UIImage? {

        guard self.numberOfSections > 0, self.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) > 0 else {
            return nil
        }

        self.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)

        var height: CGFloat = 0.0
        for section in 0..<self.numberOfSections {
            var cellHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
            for row in 0..<self.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
                guard let cell = self.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { continue }
                cellHeight = cell.frame.size.height
            }
            height += cellHeight * CGFloat(self.numberOfRows(inSection: section))
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: self.contentSize.width, height: height), false, UIScreen.main.scale)

        for section in 0..<self.numberOfSections {
            for row in 0..<self.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
                guard let cell = self.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { continue }
                cell.contentView.drawHierarchy(in: cell.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)

                if row < self.numberOfRows(inSection: section) - 1 {
                    self.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: row+1, section: section), at: .bottom, animated: false)
                }
            }
        }
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image!
    }
}
```

Comment: That works. But images is not displaying correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Just UITableView's cells to UIImage

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(tableView.contentSize.width, tableView.contentSize.height+64+40), true, 0)

for section in 0...tableView.numberOfSections-1 {
    for row in 0...tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(section)-1 {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath.init(forRow: row, inSection: section)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

        print("row:\(indexPath.row), frame:\(cell.frame) height:\(cell.frame.height)")

        cell.contentView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(cell.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }
}
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: why is it upvoted? It crashes when you try to access cell which is not visible(and is not drawn)

Answer (score 1):

To take a screenshot of a UIView you can use the following:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tableview.frame.size)
tableview.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

This will work for whatever is visible, and may work for any already loaded but off-screen views.
In an UITableView, only the visible cells plus 1 off-screen cell at each end of the table are loaded. The other ones do not actually exist... yet. So you can't "capture" them.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 version of Young Hoo Kim's answer works for me:

```
func generateTableViewImage(_ tableView: UITableView) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tableView.contentSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

    for section in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections {
        for row in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
            guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { continue }
            cell.contentView.drawHierarchy(in: cell.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

It should be noted that if your UITableView is particularly long you may not be able to capture it with the function above as it may require too large an image.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 version of Parth Bhadaja's answer:

```
func generateImage(tableView:UITableView) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tableView.contentSize);
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) as IndexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: false)
    tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let row = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
    let numberofRowthatShowinscreen = 4
    let scrollCount = row / numberofRowthatShowinscreen

    for i in 0..<scrollCount {
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: (i+1)*numberofRowthatShowinscreen, section: 0) as IndexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: false)
        tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    }

    let image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Should be noted that this function **does** return an image of the whole tableView, even cells which haven't been loaded onto the screen yet.

Comment: Not working in iOS 14 with Swift 5. Off-screen part is in while color only.

Answer (score 0):

You can create graphics context with the size of tableView.contentSize. After that you have to run loop threw all indexPaths and draw each cell. You can have one cell which will be reused for drawing cells which are out of screen - just change content of that with required data and draw it.

Answer (score 0):

add `render` method to `UITableView` through `category`

```
- (UIImage *)render {

    //save the origin info for later to restore
    CGPoint originContentOffset = self.contentOffset;

    //force jump to table view's top
    self.contentOffset = CGPointZero;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.contentSize);

    CGContextRef *ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //render header 
    [self.tableHeaderView.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    //render sections
    NSInteger numberOfSections = [self numberOfSections];
    for (int section = 0; section < numberOfSections; section++) {
        NSInteger numberOfRows = [self numberOfRowsInSection:section];
        for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
            //check cell is visible
            if ([self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]) {
                [self scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:false];
                [self.layer renderInContext:ctx];
            }
        }
    }

    //render footer
    [self.tableFooterView.layer renderInContext:ctx];
    
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //restore info
    self.contentOffset = originContentOffset;

    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same requirement to send image of tableview to admin via email, Hope this will help you.
Function implemented in swift 4

```
func screenshot() -> UIImage{
    var image = UIImage()

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.tblDetails.contentSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

    // save initial values
    let savedContentOffset = self.tblDetails.contentOffset
    let savedFrame = self.tblDetails.frame
    let savedBackgroundColor = self.tblDetails.backgroundColor

    // reset offset to top left point
    self.tblDetails.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    // set frame to content size
    self.tblDetails.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tblDetails.contentSize.width, height: self.tblDetails.contentSize.height)
    // remove background
    self.tblDetails.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    // make temp view with scroll view content size
    // a workaround for issue when image on ipad was drawn incorrectly
    let tempView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tblDetails.contentSize.width, height: self.tblDetails.contentSize.height))

    // save superview
    let tempSuperView = self.tblDetails.superview
    // remove scrollView from old superview
    self.tblDetails.removeFromSuperview()
    // and add to tempView
    tempView.addSubview(self.tblDetails)

    // render view
    // drawViewHierarchyInRect not working correctly
    tempView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    // and get image
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

    // and return everything back
    tempView.subviews[0].removeFromSuperview()
    tempSuperView?.addSubview(self.tblDetails)

    // restore saved settings
    self.tblDetails.contentOffset = savedContentOffset
    self.tblDetails.frame = savedFrame
    self.tblDetails.backgroundColor = savedBackgroundColor

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

Comment: The image correctly renders from the tableview using this code for me. However, the tableview becomes blank/white. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative solution with some little improvements:

- It scrolls the content based on content offset instead of number of rows.
- It takes into account the header and footer views (`tableHeaderView` and `tableFooterView`) if available. If you start capturing from the first row it won't get the content entirely in some cases.
- The `contentOffset` is stored before the process starts in order to set it again when scrolling + capturing is finished.

```swift
extension UITableView {
    
    var tableViewAsImage: UIImage? {
        let offset = contentOffset
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contentSize)

        guard let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return nil
        }
        setContentOffset(.zero, animated: false)
        layer.render(in: currentContext)
        
        let height = bounds.height
        let totalHeight = contentSize.height
        let scrollCount = Int((height / totalHeight).rounded())
        
        for i in 0...scrollCount {
            let y: CGFloat = CGFloat(i) * height
            setContentOffset(.init(x: 0, y: y), animated: false)
            layer.render(in: currentContext)
        }
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
        return image
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`UItableView` by don't create all cells at a time, but you can force tableView to load all (**which is not recommended**) work around is just set the height of `tableView` `( numRows * heightOfRow)` and this will make it load `tableView` all rows.
And you can convert view to image like below

```
+ (UIImage*)imageFromView:(UIView *)view{
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height) afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For snapshot in of uitableview with swift 2.2:

```
func printScreen(){
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(Table_LigaParcial.contentSize, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
    Table_LigaParcial.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
    Table_LigaParcial.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let row = Table_LigaParcial.numberOfRowsInSection(0)
    let numberofRowthatShowinscreen = 4
    var scrollCount = row / numberofRowthatShowinscreen

    for var i=0;i < scrollCount ; i+=1 {
        Table_LigaParcial.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: (i)*numberofRowthatShowinscreen, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
        Table_LigaParcial.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    }

    let image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: created a lot of cells, got an awful screenshot with broken layout and with ~75% cells only

Answer (score -1):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(self.tableView.contentSize.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height), YES, 0);

CGFloat originY = 0;

CGRect rectFirst =  CGRectMake(0, originY, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);

[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:rectFirst animated:NO];

[self.tableView drawViewHierarchyInRect:rectFirst afterScreenUpdates:true];

while (originY < self.tableView.contentSize.height) {

   CGRect rectSecond =  CGRectMake(0, originY, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);

    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible: rectSecond animated:NO];

    [self.tableView drawViewHierarchyInRect: rectSecond afterScreenUpdates:true];

    originY += self.view.bounds.size.height;

}

CGRect rectFinally =  CGRectMake(0, originY, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height - originY);

[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:rectFinally animated:NO];

[self.tableView drawViewHierarchyInRect:rectFinally afterScreenUpdates:true];

UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

It's very important to set animated to NO, and don't block the UI thread