# How can I take a screenshot of selected rows in UITableView in Swift and save it as an UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uiimage

In my `Swift` app I have a `UITableView` that contains 4 static cells and then it has different amount of dynamic cells. I want to take a screenshot only of the static cell.

I found the following extension:

```
extension UITableView {
    var capturedImage : UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contentSize);
        scrollToRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) as IndexPath, at:     UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: false)
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let row = numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
        let numberofRowthatShowinscreen = 4
        let scrollCount = row / numberofRowthatShowinscreen

        for i in 0 ..< scrollCount  {
            scrollToRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: (i+1)*numberofRowthatShowinscreen, section: 0) as     IndexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: false)
            layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        }

        let image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image;
    }
}
```

it comes from this question [How to render a whole UITableView as an UIImage in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114807/how-to-render-a-whole-uitableview-as-an-uiimage-in-ios)

But the problem is, even though I change:

```
let numberofRowthatShowinscreen = 4
```

to:

```
let numberofRowthatShowinscreen = 3
```

then it still takes a screenshot of the whole `UITableView`. Is there a way of limiting it only to first 4 rows then?

Comment: why don't you simply control your table view data source array returning `yourDataSource.prefix(4)` before calling capturedImage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample code you are rendering the layer of the table view in the image context. That will always snapshot the entire table view. You can take the advice of the commenters and adjust the cells of the table view prior to snapshotting it. Or you can snapshot the layers of the cells you want to render. For example:

```
extension UITableView
{
    func snapshotRows(at indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) -> UIImage?
    {
        guard !indexPaths.isEmpty else { return nil }
        var rect = self.rectForRow(at: indexPaths.first!)
        for indexPath in indexPaths
        {
            let cellRect = self.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
            rect = rect.union(cellRect)
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        for indexPath in indexPaths
        {
            let cell = self.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            cell?.layer.bounds.origin.y = self.rectForRow(at: indexPath).origin.y - rect.minY
            cell?.layer.render(in: context)
            cell?.layer.bounds.origin.y = 0
        }

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let image = tableView.snapshotRows(at: Set([IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)]))
```

Will only snapshot specific cells. As answers for the other post say this will only work for visible cells where cells are reused.

Comment: This method is not working in iOS 13 for dynamic height cells.