# Problems with creating image or pdf from grouped table in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pdf, export

I created `UITableView` with "Inset Grouped" style. I also applied shadow to `tableView.layer` (cell sections are shadowed).

For example I use code from here:
[How to render a whole UITableView as an UIImage in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114807/how-to-render-a-whole-uitableview-as-an-uiimage-in-ios)

```
func printScreen(){
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(Table_LigaParcial.contentSize, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
    Table_LigaParcial.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
    Table_LigaParcial.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let row = Table_LigaParcial.numberOfRowsInSection(0)
    let numberofRowthatShowinscreen = 4
    var scrollCount = row / numberofRowthatShowinscreen

    for var i=0;i < scrollCount ; i+=1 {
        Table_LigaParcial.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: (i)*numberofRowthatShowinscreen, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
        Table_LigaParcial.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    }

    let image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Slightly fixed it according to new swift version and use custom size because `tableView.contentSize` returns a wrong size:

```
    static func printScreen(tableView: UITableView){
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 375, height: 6075 + 34), false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)
        tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let row = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
        let numberofRowthatShowinscreen = 4
        var scrollCount = row / numberofRowthatShowinscreen

        for i in 0..<scrollCount {
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: (i)*numberofRowthatShowinscreen, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)
            tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        }

        let image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        if let data = image.pngData() {
            let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("copy.png")
            print(filename)
            try? data.write(to: filename)
        }
    }
```

However 2 problems persist:

- the first and the last cell becomes a rounded rect (both top as bottom corners are rounded)
- shadow looks like it consists of multiple shadows which overlap each other

Note: no matter which cell you use - it happens even with default `UITableViewCell`. So the problem should be with pdf/image export or `UITableView` by itself.

How to solve these issues with export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule (at least, from my experience) it is unusual to render a large table view as a `UIImage` or to a PDF file. More common is to format the **data** to look better on a "page" format.

However, assuming you have a valid reason to do this...

A `UITableView` does a lot of work "behind the scenes" as it manages layout, memory use, selection state, etc.

Suppose we have 100 variable-height rows, and only 6 or 7 rows can fit on the screen. When the view first appears, the table view is only going to render the rows it needs to display. At that point, it can only **guess** at the final `.contentSize.height` -- it has no way of knowing how tall any of the other 93 cells will need to be.

If the cells are all the same height, and we inform the table view with, for example, `tableView.rowHeight = 120.0`, we *do* get a valid `.contentSize`. Otherwise, with dynamic, variable height cells, we don't get a valid `.contentSize` until we have scrolled all the way to the bottom -- ***and the cells have been rendered***.

So... one approach you could take is to create **two table views**. One that is visible which the user can interact with, and one that is hidden but setup with the same properties, same cell class, same data, etc.

We then tell the hidden table view to scroll to the bottom, force it to update its layout, and then change its frame height to match its *valid* `.contentSize.height`.

Here is some example code...

I'm using `.insetGrouped`, 5 sections, each with 7 rows, every 3rd row will have multiple lines of text (to confirm we're using auto-sizing cells). I've also added a `UIImageView` that will hold the `UIImage` captured table view.

Selecting any row will capture the entire table (the hidden one) as a `UIImage` and show the image view. Tapping the image view will hide it again:

```
class RenderTableVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var tableView: UITableView!
    let capturedImageView = UIImageView()
    var outputTableView: UITableView!
    
    let nSections: Int = 5
    let nRows: Int = 7
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .insetGrouped)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        capturedImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(capturedImageView)
        
        // we need to add the "output table view" to a container view
        //  and then hide the container view
        let containerView = UIView()
        outputTableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .insetGrouped)
        containerView.addSubview(outputTableView)
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.isHidden = true

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // inset the image view 40-points on all 4 sides
            capturedImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            capturedImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            capturedImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            capturedImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
        ])
        
        tableView.register(RenderTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: RenderTableCell.identifier)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        outputTableView.register(RenderTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: RenderTableCell.identifier)
        outputTableView.dataSource = self
        outputTableView.delegate = self
        
        capturedImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        capturedImageView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        
        // start with capturedImageView hidden
        capturedImageView.isHidden = true
        
        // add a tap gesture to the image view so we can hide it on tap
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideImageView(_:)))
        capturedImageView.addGestureRecognizer(t)
        capturedImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        outputTableView.frame = tableView.frame
        outputTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: nRows - 1, section: nSections - 1), at: .top, animated: false)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.outputTableView.frame.size.height = self.outputTableView.contentSize.height
        }
    }
    
    @objc func hideImageView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        capturedImageView.isHidden = true
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return nSections
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return nRows
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: RenderTableCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! RenderTableCell
        // give every 3rd row a couple lines of text to confirm sizing works
        if indexPath.row % 3 == 0 {
            c.label.text = "\(indexPath)\nLine 2\nLine 3"
        } else {
            c.label.text = "\(indexPath)"
        }
        c.selectionStyle = .none
        return c
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if !capturedImageView.isHidden {
            capturedImageView.isHidden = true
            return()
        }

        // make sure the hidden table view layout is updated
        outputTableView.setNeedsLayout()
        outputTableView.layoutIfNeeded()

        // set its frame height to match its contentSize.height
        outputTableView.frame.size.height = outputTableView.contentSize.height
        
        // render the table view as a UIImage
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: outputTableView.frame.size)
        let imgCapture = renderer.image { ctx in
            self.outputTableView.drawHierarchy(in: .init(origin: .zero, size: self.outputTableView.frame.size), afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
        capturedImageView.image = imgCapture
        capturedImageView.isHidden = false

    }
}
```

So, looks like this on launch:

[image]

and like this after tapping a row (image view is set to `.aspectFit` with a blue background):

[image]

Comment: this is great effort but I think creating two tableview is overkilling thing , Main problem is  fetching correct content size , as small suggestion if we try to give estimated height (almost equal to cell height)  
@Gargo
in this function 
 `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat`  
and  also layoutIfNeeded() may work
Not sure if this will work  but worth to give try
@Gargo