# UITableView has wrong content size when all the inner sizes are fixed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, height, row-height

I have `UITableView` with one section (1 header view + 100 rows). Its vertical constraints are to top view's bottom and to superview's bottom (not bottom safe area).

I provided all the necessary heights manually with `UITableViewDelegate`:

- section header height
- first and last cell height
- other cells height

If I sum all these heights i get ~6000px but `tableView.contentSize.height` returns ~4500 until I scroll to the bottom of the table. And this happens even with default cells.

I understand that I can calculate everything manually but why table has wrong content size if all its inner element heights are predefined?

Comment: A `UITableView` - like most components - does a lot of "behind the scenes" work. When it loads, it doesn't *need* to calculate or render its entire **potential** content size. What are you trying to do that it matters?

Comment: I need to export to pdf. In my case I need to know contentSize to specify a pdf page size but as I understand I can calculate it manually only

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76771190/problems-with-creating-image-or-pdf-from-grouped-table-in-swift - WTF men? The linked question is about pdf/image export problems of concrete customized `UITableView` because of its shadow and rounded corners. This question is about `UITableView.contentSize` with any cells including the default `UITableViewCell` with no customisation at all. The only common thing they have is hashtag `UITableView`. How can they be duplicates?!

Comment: Sorry - I figured the answer to your other question explained why `tableView.contentSize` is not determined until you've scrolled all the way to the bottom. I assume when you say *"I provided all the necessary heights manually with `UITableViewDelegate`"* you mean you implemented `heightForRowAt`? If so, a little debugging shows that until you've scrolled the table view, `heightForRowAt` is not called on every row.

Comment: yes, I meaned `heightForRowAt` delegate method implementation and it was strange for me to see that I defined heights for each inner table element but iOS can't just sum them. Other users ask similar questions but with table with varying heights. Anyways `estimatedHeightForRowAt` (not value but delegate method) resolves this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution for my case (when all the table items' heights are predefined):
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/81895

It seems `heightForRow` delegate method determines the height of the row which is drawn/visible on the screen but is not properly involved in `contentSize` calculation.

`estimatedHeightForRowAt` looks like the opposite method. It determines the height of the row for `contentSize` calculation but without of `heightForRow` visible rows have the default height.

So it is necessary to implement both `heightForRow` and `estimatedHeightForRowAt` methods for this case.

The same is for header/footer heights (if these items are displayed)

Answer (score 1):

A `UITableView` - like most components - does a lot of "behind the scenes" work. When it loads, it doesn't need to calculate or render its entire potential content size.

Quick example to demonstrate...

**simple single label cell class**

```
class ContentSizeTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let identifier: String = "ContentSizeTableCell"
    
    let label = UILabel()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        // so we can see the framing
        label.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
    
}
```

**basic table view controller**

```
class ContentSizeTableVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var tableView: UITableView!
    
    let nSections: Int = 1
    let nRows: Int = 100

    // track the rows being asked for height
    var heightForRowMaxRow: Int = -1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])
        
        tableView.register(ContentSizeTableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ContentSizeTableCell.identifier)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return nSections
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return nRows
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ContentSizeTableCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! ContentSizeTableCell
        c.label.text = "\(indexPath)"
        return c
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        heightForRowMaxRow = max(heightForRowMaxRow, indexPath.row)
        
        // return 100 for 1st and last row
        //  50 for all other rows
        if indexPath.row == 0 ||
            indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1
        {
            return 100.0
        }
        return 50.0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("hfrMax:", heightForRowMaxRow, tableView.contentSize.height)
    }
}
```

Note in the controller class, we have this property:

```
// track the rows being asked for height
var heightForRowMaxRow: Int = -1
```

and we've implemented `heightForRowAt` like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    heightForRowMaxRow = max(heightForRowMaxRow, indexPath.row)
    
    // return 100 for 1st and last row
    //  50 for all other rows
    if indexPath.row == 0 ||
        indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1
    {
        return 100.0
    }
    return 50.0
}
```

Every time `heightForRowAt` is called, we'll set that property to the highest row number.

In `didSelectRowAt`, we'll print that property and the table view's `.contentSize.height`.

On launch, on an iPhone 14 Pro, 14 rows are visible. Selecting a row outputs this to the debug console:

```
hfrMax: 14 4540.0
```

As we see, `heightForRowAt` has been called **only** for the first 14 rows.

Scrolling a bit and selecting rows outputs this:

```
hfrMax: 33 4654.0
hfrMax: 66 4852.0
hfrMax: 99 5100.0
```

Once we've scrolled far enough so that `heightForRowAt` has been called on ALL the rows, we now have a valid `tableView.contentSize.height`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. With your hint I found a solution which resolves this problem.